# How can I decompress GZIP/DEFLATE content with HTTPWebRequest

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, httpclient

It appears that when reading the response stream from either the Microsoft HTTPClient (wrapper in 3.5 and before), or the HTTPWebResponse (.NET 4.0 and later), both instances are starting to return binary content.

We have hundreds of web spiders, many using different frameworks or "one-off" code.  And they are one by one starting to all return junk for the HTML.  I assume it's the ones we are touching and rebuilding the DLL's.  Which makes me think something changed in the framework.

This is my main method:

```
Public Function PostPage(ByVal URL As String, ByVal enc As Encoding) As String
    Try
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateCertificate)
        Dim htmlRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(URL), HttpWebRequest)
        htmlRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
        Dim htmlResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(htmlRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Return New System.IO.StreamReader(htmlResponse.GetResponseStream(), enc).ReadToEnd()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return ""
End Function
```

It's very basic, I'm not sure what's going on, every type of encoding (including not specifying any encoding) returns binary.  This is a working representation of what's breaking when I input even `http://www.google.com` as the URL.

Comment: Downvote?  That's never happened to me before... Could somebody please let me know what I need to do here to make that go away, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're adding the Accept-Encoding header, you're telling the web server: "Please send me a response that is compressed using GZIP or DEFLATE."

The webserver dutifully returns such a response and your client gets the compressed content. If you want to decompress that content, you must do so manually if your object does not support automatic decompression.

Rather than adding the Accept-Encoding header manually, instead tell .NET to do it and to automatically decompress the response on your behalf.

`htmlRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;`

Comment: Thank you, I like using the object properties instead of the string input.  I tested it with the properties and it works. `htmlRequest.AutomaticDecompression = (DecompressionMethods.Deflate Or DecompressionMethods.GZip)`.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the question: believing it was the Encoding, I wrote a loop that loops through all possible encodings, including UTF8 and UTF7, and even Italian and other languages and everything. (139 I think it was).  It stored the Encoding Name and the HTML Result in a Dictionary, which I then reviewed and saw it was all junk.

```
Sub LearnEncoding(ByVal MyURL As String)
    Dim dctResults As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    For Each objEncoding In System.Text.Encoding.GetEncodings
        If dctResults.ContainsKey(objEncoding.DisplayName) = False Then
            Dim MySpider As New clsWebSpider
            dctResults.Add(objEncoding.DisplayName, MySpider.PostPage(MyURL, objEncoding.GetEncoding))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

After a lot of research and testing, I found the issue was in:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

What!?!?

That is in by default in the MSHTTPClient, and is naturally there when you review the headers in Fiddler from Browser requests.  Of course, Browsers don't care about junk, they seem to be able to decode anything.  I don't write decoders though.

So for many of our spiders using MSHTTPClient, we called DefaultHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Clear(), and for our HttpWebRequests, we just removed the setting line for AcceptEncoding.  They all return good HTML again.  I researched changes to the framework, but couldn't find anything that explains it.